# How to bold part of text trough code, not manually

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using react.js.

I am making the JSON with labels, which later will be rendered trough loop.

And some parts of labels should be bold, is there a way to do something like this?

```
{
labelSub: `"TX Group" ${<b>AND</b>} "Latest News"`
}
```

Comment: You need to place variables inside ${} and not AND like that

Comment: Ah right, or I can do like this? ${<b>'AND'</b>} ?

Comment: But I have problem to export this as list...

Comment: You need to render like this https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-darkness-vhu48 , let me know if this works, il write an answer

Comment: You can also consider using Markdown syntax. Then you can install any third party library that parses Markdown and render it to html.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind `html` as a `string` you need to use [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). You don't need string template either. So your variable definition will look like

```
const label = {labelSub: `"TX Group" ${<b>AND</b>} "Latest News"`}
```

In your JSX

```
<label dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: label}}></label>
```

Cheers!!